# Search specific text, one column at a time, and copy data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet in which I am managing a rate list. It has two sheets.

The output sheet.
[image]

It has `18` columns. The columns from `K` to `Z` contain the price list. In these columns there are many cells that contain `No price` value instead of price in `$`.

I want to filter the columns one by one and copy all the rows that contains `No price` to another sheet.

I have written a macro using multiple if statements but I am not getting the required output.

```
Sub FilterNoPrice()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myRow As Variant                '### NOTE THIS CHANGE!
    Sheets("Output").Select

    Set myRange = Range("K3:K10000")

    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)

    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("K:K").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        'MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("L3:L10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("L:L").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        'MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("M3:M10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("M:M").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("N3:N10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("N:N").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If        

    Set myRange = Range("O3:O10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("O:O").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If        

    Set myRange = Range("P3:P10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("P:P").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("Q3:Q10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q:Q").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If        

    Set myRange = Range("R3:R10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("S3:S10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("S:S").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If        

    Set myRange = Range("T3:T10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("T:T").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("U3:U10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("U:U").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("V3:V10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("V:V").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

    Set myRange = Range("W3:W10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("W2:W10000").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If        

    Set myRange = Range("X3:X10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("X:X").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If          

    Set myRange = Range("Y3:Y10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("Y:Y").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If          

    Set myRange = Range("Z3:Z10000")
    myRow = Application.Match("No price", myRange, False)
    If Not IsError(myRow) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("Z:Z").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="No price"
        ' and then select/activate the cell:
        'Application.GoTo Cells(1, myRow)
    Else
        ' The value is not found in the range, so inform you:
        MsgBox "Not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Right now you are incrementing the field when there is only 1 column. So the field will always be 1. BTW No need to have so many filters. You can have one range `K:L` and then simply in the loop change The `field:=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, there is no need to so have individual filter codes for each column. You can have just one range `K:L` and then simply in the loop change the `field:=` as shown below

Let's assume your sheet looks like this

[image]

Paste this code in a **Module**. I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. But if you do then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range

    '~~> Change the name of the sheets as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1
    Set wsOutput = Sheet2

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row in the sheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            MsgBox "No Data Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        '~~> Set your filter range
        Set rng = .Range("K2:Z" & lastrow)

        '~~> Loop through the range
        For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            .AutoFilterMode = False

            '~~> Filter the range and store the filtered range
            '~~> if applicable in a range object
            With rng
                .AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="No price"

                If rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToCopy = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                Else
                    Set rngToCopy = Union(rngToCopy, .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
                End If
            End With
        Next i

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Clear output sheet and copy data across
        If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then
            wsOutput.Cells.Clear
            .Range("K2:Z2").Copy wsOutput.Cells(1, 1) '<~~ Copy Headers
            rngToCopy.Copy wsOutput.Cells(2, 1) '<~~ Copy Filtered Data
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: I have tested your code but it gives an error "No Data available". When I debug it, I found that when the first loop check the column K and found could not find "No Price" it activates the filter and the filter remain active. But the logic should be like that if the loop visit column k and it should check either the "No Price" text is present in the column or not. If text found than the fitler should be active and loop needs to move next column while in current situation instead of moving next column it start copying data that is wrong. Please recheck it. thanks

Comment: The filter gets reset becuase of `.AutoFilterMode = False` inside the for loop. If you do not need the filter to reset then simply remove that line